# How to update google sheets 'edit date' column when the google document has a new edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I was asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049232/is-it-possible-to-get-a-google-doc-modified-date-within-a-google-sheets-or-apps/74049353?noredirect=1#comment130748785_74049353) that was answered but I did't specify my situation perfectly.

So the situation is that I want to insert the google doc modify date into the sheet based on google docId. The below function push a dates on demand.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues()
    .map(([id]) => {
      if (id.toString() == "") return [null];
      return [id ? DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated() : null];
    });
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

However also I want to push the new edit date once the related google doc changed. I wonder if it is possible to achieve?

Comment: If you want to detect the updated date when the file is updated immediately, I think that ["Changes"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes) of Drive API can be used. But, in this case, I'm worried that the setting might be a bit complicated. So, if you can permit several minutes after the file is updated, how about using a time-driven trigger? When the time-driven trigger is used, you can simply and periodically check the updated date. But, if those were not useful information, I apologize.

Comment: several minutes delay if fine

Comment: do you need to track that `changes` for each doc file?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that the script is not required to be modified. I thought that you can just install the time-driven trigger to your showing script. And, about `do you need to track that changes for each doc file?`, in this case, the file ID of the updated file can be known.

Comment: For example, when the file is updated, there are what you want to do something except for updating the updated date?

Comment: oh I haven't thought of it yet, may be in the future yes, but for now just need a `modified date` to be pushed to that sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, as a simple method, when you install the time-driven trigger to your showing script `myFunction()` as 5 minutes (for example), the script can be run every 5 minutes. The script overwrites column "B". By this, I thought that your goal can be achieved. The official document of the triggers can be seen at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

Comment: oh I c so you proposing to schedule the script, right? so there is no way to push the `modify date` to the sheet?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `push the modify date to the sheet`?

Comment: yes what I mean is that instead of pulling the `modified dates` all at once by running `myFunction()` , what I meant is to update automatically when doc changes, if you see what I mean

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to run the script when the file is updated, "Changes" of Drive API can be used. You can see the official document for using it. And, as another direction, when you can run the script periodically, how about using [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2). When this API is checked periodically, when the specific file is updated, you can know it. But, I'm not sure whether this is included in the direction of your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: If you can run the script periodically, I would like to recommend using the time-driven trigger because the script and the setting are simpler.