# Is there a way to show the user or email of who last modified a spreasheet based on google doc ID (URL/Link)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am very new to app script and only have experience with formulas in google sheets/excel but not familiar with language of script yet! I was able to find this script below that pulls in the last modified date of the file based on the link which is great! But I would like to add to this script to also pull the email or username of the user who last modified it, I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I am still new and learning but any help would be appreciated thank you so much in advance!!

Below is the script i found and modified that you enter in link ID in column H and it populates the last modified date of the file in next column. I would like this to stay the same except add another column with the user or email who modified it.

```
function myFunction() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
const range = sheet.getRange("h2:h" + sheet.getLastRow());
const values = range.getRichTextValues()
  .map(([a]) => {
    const link = a.getLinkUrl();
    if (!link) return [null];
    const id = link.split("/")[5];
    return [id ? DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated() : null];
  });
range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
```

}

added 11/8/2023:@tanaike below is script I copied.  The script is working and returning what i was looking for, however after it runs i receive the error message *"Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2."* Again thank you so much for your help!

```
function myFunction() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const range = sheet.getRange("h2:h" + sheet.getLastRow());
const values = range.getRichTextValues()
.map(([a]) => {
  const link = a.getLinkUrl();
  if (!link) return [null];
  const id = link.split("/")[5];
  if (id) {
    const { lastModifyingUser: { displayName }, modifiedDate } = Drive.Files.get(id, { fields: "lastModifyingUser,modifiedDate" });
    return [new Date(modifiedDate), displayName]; 
  }
  return [null, null];
});
range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: If you are using [the script of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74049353), I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result from `know if certain column within certain tab of that link url has been updated.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you so much for quick response! Yes, I used that script you linked (it was very helpful!). What I am looking for is for example I want the date that column B on Sheet2 of the link URL was last modified (currently only gives date the file was last modified, but i only need to know the date if Column B on Sheet2 of the URL link was changed only. I am sorry if my question does not make sense, I can provide further detail example if needed. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I have a question. In your situation, how many Spreadsheets do you want to retrieve your expected value? Although, unfortunately, I'm worried that there might be a method for directly achieving your goal if my understanding of your goal is correct, I thought that a workaround might be able to be proposed by the number of Spreadsheets in your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I have very large amount over 500 spreadsheets. But the column and sheet that I am looking to see if modified is the same sheet name and column in all  500+ spreadsheets. I am open to any solution! To further explain, I have over 500 clients with separate files (all the same template, sheets, columns etc) and I want one file to know if they have been last updated in column B on Sheet2.

Comment: If this is too much work, if I could add the username or email of last modified date as is, this would also be solution to work!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply (`I have very large amount over 500 spreadsheets.`), I think that in this case, it is difficult to directly achieve your goal. But, I think that your other goal of `if I could add the username or email of last modified date as is, this would also be solution to work!` can be achieved. In this case, do you want to change your question?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you again for your response, yes If i can add the username or email of the user who last modified to the current script, that would be great! I just changed the question , I apologize as I am new to this forum so please let me know if there is any other information you need from me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the Spreadsheet URLs in column "H" of "Sheet1".
- You want to retrieve the last modified date and the modified user information and want to put them into columns "I" and "J".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("h2:h" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getRichTextValues()
    .map(([a]) => {
      const link = a.getLinkUrl();
      if (!link) return [null];
      const id = link.split("/")[5];
      if (id) {
        const { lastModifyingUser: { displayName, emailAddress }, modifiedDate } = Drive.Files.get(id, { fields: "lastModifyingUser,modifiedDate" });
        return [new Date(modifiedDate), emailAddress]; // return [new Date(modifiedDate), displayName];
      }
      return [null, null];
    });
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the modified date and the modified user's email are put into columns "I" and "J", respectively.
- If you want to use the display name of the user, please modify the return value to `return [new Date(modifiedDate), displayName]`.
- If you want to retrieve only the user's information, please modify `return [new Date(modifiedDate), emailAddress]` to `return [emailAddress]` and `return [null, null]` to `return [null]`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/get)

Comment: you are the best! thank you so much for helping me!! This is working perfect and returning the information I need, but I get the below message error "Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2.".... The script is working perfectly, but It is showing this message and I am not sure what it means?

Comment: @Alianna Thank you for replying. From `you are the best! thank you so much for helping me!! This is working perfect and returning the information I need`, I understood that my answer resolved your issue.

Comment: @Alianna About `but I get the below message error "Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2."`, I think that in this case, I'm worried that you might have miscopied my proposed script. So, can you provide your current script? By this, I will be able to notice the reason for your current issue.

Comment: I could not fit code in comment so I added to the original question starting with *added 11/8/2023* To show the current code. The script resolved my issue, but in addition to this, it is showing this error after the script runs so I am just not sure I may have done something wrong. Thank you again!!

Comment: @Alianna Thank you for replying. When I saw your added script, I think that in this case, the error of `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2.` doesn't occur. So, in this case, it is required to confirm your sample Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your current issue. Can you provide your sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.